# Check if word in english dictionary programmatically in c#

Tags: c#, text, spell-checking

I want to check if a word is in English dictionary and make it a tag. All i know is that NetSpell has a dll but i don't know how to check it.

Comment: A dictionary isn't going to catch that mistake.

Comment: If you want to check something against a 3rd party DLL you'll need the API documentation.

Comment: I solved it.. People should stop reducing my reputation.

Comment: If you solved it, post the solution as an answer. That way, you can help everyone.

Comment: New users can't answer their own question for 8 hours. Please use comments, or edit your question instead. I have to wait.. that is why i edited it... come on guys stop reduce my reputation...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
NetSpell.SpellChecker.Dictionary.WordDictionary oDict = new NetSpell.SpellChecker.Dictionary.WordDictionary(); 

oDict.DictionaryFile = "en-US.dic"; 
//load and initialize the dictionary 
oDict.Initialize();
string txtWords = Company;
NetSpell.SpellChecker.Spelling oSpell = new NetSpell.SpellChecker.Spelling(); 

oSpell.Dictionary = oDict; 
char []chDelims = {' ','\n', '\t', '\r'};
foreach (string s in txtWords.Split(chDelims)) 
{ 
    if (s.Length > 0 && oSpell.TestWord(s)) 
    { 
        //Do something here...
    } 
}
```